# "Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, submit

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong with this code? I tried to submit a form with JavaScript, but an error ".submit is not a function" shown. See below for more details of the code:

```
<form action="product.php" method="get" name="frmProduct" id="frmProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input onclick="submitAction()" id="submit_value" type="button" name="submit_value" value="">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitAction()
    {
        document.frmProduct.submit();
    }
</script>
```

I also tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitAction()
    {
        document.forms["frmProduct"].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Both show me the same error  :(

Comment: Which browser gives you this message? Can you post the complete source?

Comment: Considering that the posted code works for me in both IE7 and Chrome2, then perhaps there is something wrong in code you haven't posted?

Comment: Perhaps you have a field with the name or id submit and thus .submit() is shadowed by that field?

Comment: that error occurred when you have  same id="frmProduct" in different elements.

Answer (score 916, accepted):

> submit is not a function

means that you named your submit button or some other element `submit`. Rename the button to `btnSubmit` and your call will magically work.

When you name the button submit, you override the `submit()` function on the form.

Comment: Just ran into this problem with selenium. "submit" seems to be the standard name for submit buttons in typo3 frontend logins. >.<

Comment: Here's a handy trick. If you're stuck with your submit button being `#submit`, you can get around it by stealing another form instance's `submit()` method, eg: `document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.frmProduct)`.

Comment: Seems everyone has to learn this one the hard way. Would make a good job interview question

Comment: I simply removed the name='submit' and Bob's your Aunty it worked!!

Comment: I just wasted my 2-3 hours for this issue, thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: In case it helps anyone else: I had an `id='submit'` on the button that was throwing things off (removing/renaming the name attribute was not sufficient).

Comment: @kayge Just had this issue and had to update the id as well.

Comment: JavaScript really is the worst ever

Comment: @NeilE.Pearson Can you explain with other words so hopeful I understand. You mean rewrite `submit()` to another name and then use it?

Comment: @Timo no. It's a way to access the prototypical `submit` function that's been made inaccessible by overriding it with something else.

Comment: "When you name the button submit, you override the submit() function on the form." - this is the thing! Thank you

Comment: The reason why naming the button "submit" overrides the function is because referencing a string after the form object in JavaScript fetches the form ELEMENT with that name OR id. So if you had `<input type="text" name="telephone">` inside the form, then `form.telephone` will return that element. And of course, `form.telephone()` will error saying that it's not a function.

Answer (score 25):

Make sure that there is no another form with the same name and make sure that there is no `name="submit"` or `id="submit"` in the form.

Answer (score 19):

If you have no opportunity to change `name="submit"` you can also submit form this way:

```
function submitForm(form) {
    const submitFormFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(form).submit;
    submitFormFunction.call(form);
}
```

Comment: `HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form)` also works

Answer (score 15):

```
<form action="product.php" method="post" name="frmProduct" id="frmProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input id="submit_value" type="button" name="submit_value" value="">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit_value").onclick = submitAction;

function submitAction()
{
    document.getElementById("frmProduct").submit();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

EDIT: I accidentally swapped the id's around

Comment: document.getElementById("frmProduct").submit is not a function :(

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the id 'frmProduct'?

Comment: Adding submitAction as a handler for onsubmit and then invoking submit from it may create an infinite loop.  The handler should be associated with onclick of the button.

Comment: Downvoting accurate answers huh? lame guys, step on us to get those points you're selling your souls for

Comment: @Chad Grant - Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Is there a way to submit it while overwriting the submit value?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when i was creating a MVC application using with master pages.
Tried looking for element with 'submit' as names as mentioned above but it wasn't the case.

For my case it created multiple  tags on my page so there were some issues referencing the correct form.

To work around this i'll let the button handle which form object to use:

```
onclick="return SubmitForm(this.form)"
```

and with the js:

```
function SubmitForm(frm) {
    frm.submit();
}
```

Comment: This wont work in his case because he had an element named "submit" which effectively replaces the submit function...

Answer (score 6):

`form.submit()` will not work if the form does not have a `<button type="submit">submit</button>`. `form` element belongs to `HTMLFormElement` interface, therefore, we can call from prototype directly, this method will always work for any form element.

```js
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

This topic has a lot of answers already, but the one that worked best (and simplest - one line!) for me was a modification of the comment made by Neil E. Pearson from Apr 21 2013:

> If you're stuck with your submit button being #submit, you can get around it by stealing another form instance's submit() method.

My modification to his method, and what worked for me:

`document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById(frmProduct));`

Comment: This is more a workaround than an answer, and ideally you'd just not name things `submit` because you're trampling the kernel. Not that anything in the JS world is ideal :D

Comment: I tried this but I get Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and resolved my issue just remove name="submit" from submit button.

```
<button name='submit' value='Submit Payment' ></button>
```

**Change To**

```
<button value='Submit Payment' ></button>
```

remove name attribute hope it will work

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem that my submit() wasn't working. In my case, I'd an id="submit" on the input tag having type="submit", I removed the id, and it started working.

Comment: Same happens if your submit has `name="submit"`. I mean wtf :/

Answer (score 2):

giving a form element a name of submit will simple shadow the submit property .
make sure you don't have a form element with the name submit and you should be able to access the submit function just fine .

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the solution is very easy...

Original:

```
    <form action="product.php" method="get" name="frmProduct" id="frmProduct"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input onclick="submitAction()" id="submit_value" type="button" 
    name="submit_value" value="">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitAction()
    {
        document.frmProduct.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Solution:

```
    <form action="product.php" method="get" name="frmProduct" id="frmProduct" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>

<!-- Place the button here -->
<input onclick="submitAction()" id="submit_value" type="button" 
    name="submit_value" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitAction()
    {
        document.frmProduct.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this solves the OP's problem.

Comment: For sure, in this case (only in this case) the trouble is the scope.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer late but for those who are still facing the same error. To get rid of this error:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit-form" value="Submit Form" style="display: none;"/>
</form>

<!-- Other element that will submit the form -->
<button onclick="submitTheForm()">Submit the form</button>

<script>
function submitTheForm(){
  document.getElementById("submit-form").click();
}
</script>
```

**Explanation:**

The javascript function `submitTheForm()` is accessing the submit `input` element and calling the click event on it which results in the `form` submission.

This solution is lifetime and almost 100% compatible in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions -
1.Make sure that you don't have any other element with name/id as submit.
2.Try to call the function as `onClick = "return submitAction();"`
3.`document.getElementById("form-name").submit();`

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code :

```js
$(document).on("ready", function () {
       
        document.frmProduct.submit();
    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

What I used is

```
var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");
enviar.type = "submit";
```

Just because everything else didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to set the "form" attribute of button

```
<form id="form_id_name"><button name="btnSubmit" form="form_id_name" /></form>
```

or is js:

```
YOURFORMOBJ.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("form", "form_id_name");
YOURFORMOBJ.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issues also but i made a quick fix using

```
const form = document.getElementById('create_user_form');

function onSubmit(event) {
  console.log(event.target[0].value);

  console.log(form.submit); // ️ input#submit

  // ✅ Works
  HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
```

Even though accessing the submit property on the form element points to the submit input element and not the method, we can still submit the form by accessing the submit property on the HTMLFormElement interface.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
<form action="product.php" method="get" name="frmProduct" id="frmProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input onclick="submitAction(this)" id="submit_value" type="button" name="submit_value" value="">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitAction(element)
{
    element.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Don't you have more than one form with the same name ?

Answer (score -2):

Use getElementById:

```
document.getElementById ('frmProduct').submit ()
```