# How to submit values by post using an action, method in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a question, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

```
<s:form name="form1" method="post" action="products" theme="simple">
  <s:hidden name="code" value="%{code}"/>
  <s:submit type="button" name="method:selectSale" value="goPage"/>
</s:form>
```

This code has no problem.

But, I want to use "anchor" instead of "submit" tag. I just want to use hyperlink and 'post' way, not 'get'. How can I do this?

```
<s:form name="form1" method="post" action="products" theme="simple">
  <s:hidden name="code" value="%{code}"/>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.form1.submit()">goPage</a>
</s:form>
```

It doesn't work.

The main problem is how to get "method:selectSale".

in struts.xml,

```
<action name="products" class="sample.ProductsAction">
  <result>abc.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and then, in ProductsAction.java,

```
public String selectSale() throws Exception {
  // ~~~
  return "selectSale"
}
```

Ok, now, I have a question.

where do i have to put `"selectSale"` on code? ( using `<s:a>` or `<a:>` )

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to set an ID property on your form, and in the onclick of the anchor use document.getElementById(formID).submit().

Comment: but, main problem is : how to get "method:selectSale".

in struts.xml,

<action name="products" class="sample.ProductsAction">
  <result>abc.jsp</result>
</action>

and then, in ProductsAction.java,

public String selectSale() throws Exception {
  ~~~
  return "selectSale"
}


ok, now, i have a question.

where do i have to put "selectSale" on code?

Answer (score 0):

```
action="products?method:selectSale"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go

```
 <s:url action="abc" method="mymethod"></s:url>
```

and if you want to pass some query string parameters can always use `<s:param>` like

```
<s:url action="abc" method="mymethod"> 
   <s:param name="id" value="%{myvalue}" />
</s:url>
```

this is a build in struts2 tag where it will resolve the URL and method is what you have defined in your struts config file

define your struts config file as

```
<action name="products" class="sample.ProductsAction" method=mymethod>
  <result>abc.jsp</result>
</action>
```

hope it willhelp you

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Change your action definition in struts.xml as :

```
<action name="products" class="sample.ProductsAction" method="selectSale">
```

**Step 2**

I guess you might be facing one of the following errors in your javascript :

[Submit is not a function in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684271/submit-is-not-a-function-in-js)

http://forums.hscripts.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3268

["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-in-javascript)

Although all three point to the same solution. For now, just define the anchor tag outside the `</s:form>` and make sure there's no element with `name=submit`

If it still doesn't work, change javascript to

```
document.forms["form1"].submit();
```