# Submit is not a function in js

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, struts2

I have a struts 2 form tag,i am trying to submit the form using the java script function.But when i try to do this i am getting the following error.

```
"document.testForm.submit is not a function" IE 8(Object doesn't support this property or method)
```

Here is my java script function and html code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function testFunction()
        {
          document.testForm.action = "testAction";
           document.testForm.submit();

        }
</script>

<s:form method="POST"  id="fileForm" name="testForm"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>
             <input type="button" name="submit" value="Upload File"    onclick="testFunction();"/>
           </td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</s:form>
```

I am using FF 7 and IE 8

Please help me out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that you've named your submit button "submit":

```
<input type="button" name="submit" ...>
<!--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  -->
```

Change it to just about anything else. Form elements get added as properties to the form object using their names, so that shadows (overrides) the form's built-in `submit` property (which is the function you're looking for).

Comment: Thank you ,Saved the day

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the name of your submit-button. Change it to `name="Submit"` or something else and try again.