# Setting a value in MVC Sitemap node and accessing it in the action to differentiate, which button was clicked by user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I set a value in MVC SiteMap Node and Access it in the action.

I am attaching an image file with my problem scenario and my question?

[image]

Can some one suggest me, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do they need to call the same action?  Setting a different action for each button and pulling the common code into a function would be a simple solution.

Comment: @Jason Berkan: I want to use same action, and use, if condition to see, what button clicked, I would like to consider your opinion, but trying to find any way, to set a value and access it in my action? Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714028/mvc-which-submit-button-has-been-pressed for determining what button was pressed, though I'm not sure how much control you have over the rendered HTML when using an mvcSiteMap.