# Disable Client Side validation for one submit button in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created the view in MVC 4.0 and i have placed four text boxes and two submit buttons, one for create and one for cancel. Validation should be occur for the text boxes while i am clicking the create button. while clicking the cancel button, we need disable the validation. in ASP.NET, we can achieve this by setting the CausesValidation = false for the cancel button.
in MVC 4.0, how we will achieve this?
Could you please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: make the class of that button as cancel

Comment: You can simply use ActionLink to redirect user to different action.

Comment: asp.net mvc validations only for work for input type submit not for input type button...so make cancel button input type button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't have to make a cancel button **submit** instead you can make it **link button**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Back","ActionName")
```

or you can make it `<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="JsFunction()" />`
the two cases they will not affect with validation

Answer (score 9):

Just add `class="cancel"` to the button

For example,

```
<input type="submit" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" class="cancel"/>
```

**Updated**

Use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714028/mvc-which-submit-button-has-been-pressed) to identify which submit button has been pressed.

Comment: if i add "cancel" css class, it prevents the client side validation. in my case, i want to call the different action method in the same controller while clicking the cancel button. now it calls the same action method

Comment: But, you specifically asked to avoid client side validation on cancel button. However, I have updated my answer and added link where you'll get idea how to do that.

Comment: What does the class `cancel` do here? Is that a class jquery validation looks at before running client side validation?