# Cannot detect which Submit Button is pressed

Tags: model-view-controller, razorengine, submit-button

I have two input type submit on my view.

1. `<input type="submit" name="submitbutton1" value="Save">`

2.`<input type="submit" name="submitbutton2" value="Process">`

My view is Manage.vbhtml and in that view i have a form with the above two submit buttons.

My controller is **StaffController** and '**Function Manage(item as staff,submitbutton1 as string,submitbutton2 as string) as ActionResult**' is associated with the above view. When i click any of the two submit buttons i should be getting the value of that button in the string parameter, but it's giving me nothing. Please help me, i want to detect which submit button was pressed. The mentioned actionresult has `<HttpPost> _` in the attribute.

I have followed as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392468/how-to-detect-which-submit-button-was-clicked-in-asp-net-mvc) but still no result.

Comment: is routing have to do anything with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it from `FormCollection`:

in Html:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Save">
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Process">
```

and in Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage()
{

   var temp = Request.Form["submitbutton"].ToString();

   if(temp == "Save")
   {
     // save clicked
   }
   if(temp == "Process")
   {
     // Process clicked
   }

    return View();

}
```

or:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(FormCollection form)
{

   var temp = form["submitbutton"].ToString();

   if(temp == "Save")
   {
     // save clicked
   }
   if(temp == "Process")
   {
     // Process clicked
   }

    return View();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck. Form does not contain the key named "submitbutton". The same think works on my other controller and its method, but not on this controller and method.

Comment: Make sure buttons are inside form

Comment: Hey dude, i think i have found the problem. Well i am passing "Staff" model to that view and it has email-id as one of the property. I have used remote validation for that property. The validation is working but it "Return Json(True, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)" so when ever i click the button it sends nothing for "submitbutton". Is there any chance that i can modify my validation code ?

Comment: Okies figured the solution - I was supposed to change my <button> to <input> and in the css class i was supposed to pass "cancel" class so that client side validation was prevented and on click i was getting full post back and thus the button names.