# Assign a value to ViewBag varible inside the <input> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have cshtml view page with paginations

here view of that page

[image]

Once I click any of below number (which is 1 to 10)  I should be able to pass that number to POST method of that form

this is the relevant cshtml code snippet to that pagination

```
   @if (Model.Pager.EndPage > 1)
                    {
                        <ul class="pagination">
                        @for (var page = Model.Pager.StartPage; page <= Model.Pager.EndPage; page++)
                        {
                                <li class="@(page == Model.Pager.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                                   <input type="submit" value=@page class="btn btn-default" ViewBag.pagenumber=@page/>
                                </li>
                        }
                       </ul>
                    }
```

then I try to pass that value like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("method_name", "controller", new { pagenumber = ViewBag.pagenumber} , FormMethod.Post))
{
```

but `pagenumber` getting null each time, in this way

---

**EDIT:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult method_name(int? page,string Product_ID)
    {
     ........
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult method_name(AddNewProduct product, string pagenumber)
    {
    .....
    return RedirectToAction("method_name", "controller", new { page = pagenumber});
    }
```

Comment: You should also share your controller code. Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Are you trying to put ViewBag value to the input or trying to post the value to controller using ViewBag from input?

Comment: Why are you assigning ViewBag in your view. 
Try this `@using (Html.BeginForm("method_name", "controller", new { pagenumber = Model.Pager.CurrentPage } , FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: @adiga actually I want to assign the page of that I'm clicking , not current page

Comment: @AnilPanwar I'm trying to post the value to controller using ViewBag from input , but this value is dynamic , it can be 1-10 value, that's why I'm trying to assign moment I'm clicking

Comment: @kez yes, my bad. If page number is the only parameter you need, you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1714311/3082296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like

Add class pagerBtn in the pager buttons

```
<input type="submit" value=@page class="btn btn-default pagerBtn"/>
```

Make a hidden input field in the form

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("method_name", "controller" , FormMethod.Post))
{
      //Make sure the action parameter same as name of input field
    <input type="hidden" name="pagenumber" id="hiddenInput" />
}
```

Write jquery to get page number

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".pagerBtn").on("click",function(e){
   var pageClicked = e.target.value;//Get clicked button page number from attribute value.
 $("#hiddenInput").val(pageClicked);//insert clicked value in hidden filed input with name same as controller parameter taking this value.

});
});
```

Comment: how to pass this value  to post method ?

Comment: Updated the answer please review again, as i have inserted the hidden input filed in the form, thus this value will be post in the form it self and action parameter will catch this page value as the name of the hidden input and action parameter is same, hope you got an idea by now.

Comment: why this `<input type="hidden"..`

Comment: This will keep the value of clicked page number, if your pager button is not inside the form.

Comment: in this approach , can it grab model values also , instead parameters ?

Comment: Yes, you will get other things as it is, if you are using strong type and if not then the input name should be same as the name of the parameters.I can see your code and it will work fine, go on.

Comment: Still `pagenumber` is null , once I debug this using firebut I can see following error `TypeError: e.target.attr is not a function`

Comment: Use e.target.value instead e.target.attr("value"), updated code as well.

Answer (score 0):

in ViewBag value becomes null when redirection occurs.
try to use TempData

```
   <input type="submit" value=@page class="btn btn-default" TempData["pagenumber"]=@page/> 

    @using (Html.BeginForm("method_name", "controller", new { pagenumber = TempData["pagenumber"]} , FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: could you please refer me an example

Answer (score 0):

Assign a name tag to each input field. In that way you could retrieve the values in the controller using a FormCollection and don't need the `new { pagenumber = ViewBag.pagenumber}`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult method_name(FormCollection collection){
  var inputValue = collection.GetValue("name").AttemptedValue;
  return RedirectToAction("method_name", "controller", inputValue);
}
```