# MVC: How Do I Link An Input Button To A Different Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have this link in Home.cshtml (This has an ActionResult of `public ActionResult Home()`)

```
<li class="home-links home-middleLast">@Html.ActionLink("Log out", "LogOut", "Home")</li>
```

It is suppose to link to this controller

```
// /LogOut
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    TempData.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    getDB.Close();
    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

I made this happen using this

```
[Route("~/log_out")]
```

and this

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

My concern is that someone could type in `/log_out` into the url and it would log out of the account. How can I make it so that people won't do that?

I want to make it so you have to click the link to log out instead of typing in `/log_out` into the url.

Comment: You can decorate the action with an AntiForgeryToken attribute, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks) for details. That will require your logout button to be in a form however.

Comment: I don't see any foolproof way to accomplish this. Anyone can open the network tab in web inspector, get the URL, and replay it.

Comment: @DanWilson Is there an if statement I can use to tell whether the button was clicked or not?

Comment: Sure, you can put the button in a form and set a hidden input flag when it is clicked and POSTed to `LogOut`.

Comment: @maccettura Maybe I could use a post button and make a bool determining if the button was pressed.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko you don’t need a bool. Just lookup AntiForgeryToken. This allows the action to _only_ be hit by a button action. Which means no one can just hit the URL

Comment: @maccettura What If I had multiple buttons?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko each one has its own token that is verified in the action attribute. Read the article I linked and try it out.

Comment: @maccettura I didn't get the link

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko check my very first comment

Comment: @maccettura Forms won't work form me. I tried using a form but it won't access the LogOut Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <li class="home-links home-middleLast"><input type="submit" value="Log out"/></li>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
[Route("~/home")]
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    TempData.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    getDB.Close();
    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

I put the home route on the LogOut Controller as well is HttpPost. This will only hit when the button is pressed.

EDIT: I didn't use the previous answer I submitted. I actually used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194770/6804700

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a dumb way.. but you can try this

```
<li class="home-links home-middleLast"><form action="@Url.Action("LogOut","Home")" method="post"><button type="submit">Log Out</button></form></li>
```

and add [HttpPost] above your action

```
//LogOut
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    TempData.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    getDB.Close();
    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

but... you must change Log Out button and style it so it looks like a link with css

Comment: It won't work for me. The problem is it won't access the LogOut Controller because it is in the Home Controller.

Comment: hmm... its weird... i assume you have a LogOut method inside HomeController, because of that, i use @Url.Action("LogOut","Home") as a URL form action.

Comment: The problem is the login controller is not routed in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This needs script:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log out", "LogOut", "Home", null, new { @class= "logout-btn" })

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".logout-btn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        // change to your location
                        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the Action:

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        TempData.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        getDB.Close();
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json("Invalid request", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Isn't using jquery or javascript bad? I believe people could manipulate this code in a negative way.

Comment: That's a topic for another question, which you probably couldn't post here without javascript.