# Pass arguments to a C# controller method using <button> and jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a bootstrap modal which has many buttons which help to download files of different formats. I am able to enter the controller method when I use the set the onclick function as below:

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadAsJPG", "Home")'"
```

I would like to do some condition based file downloading, based on the button that was pressed and hence I was thinking of passing a parameter as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714034/5657937) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714311/5657937) by setting the value attribute of the buttons

**HTML :**

```
<button type="button" id="tojpg" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="jpg">JPG</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="jpgcmyk">JPG-CMYK</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="jpgrgb">JPG-RGB</button>
```

The argument in the controller method always remains null. I'm not sure what I have missed.

**Controller method:**

```
public FileResult DownloadAsJpg(string argument)
{ Some action }
```

I tried to play with a jquery which I found on a stackoverflow question which doesn't help me either, I couldn't reach the controller using this jquery.

**Jquery**

```
$('#tojpg').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = '/Home/DownloadAsJpg?argument=' + $('#tojpg').val();
    });
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that by any chance you've missed `/api/` in your url ? So the url is smth like`/Api/Home/DownloadAsJpg?argument=`. What error do you get ?

Comment: @Fabjan, I added an alert into the function and it doesn't seem to capture the button events. I'm not sure if this is because of the bootstrap modal. I'm checking this.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine (although there are better ways to do it). What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, No errors, Could you suggest me the right way of doing this?

Comment: You can just use `@Html.Actionlink("JPG", "DownloadAsJPG", "Home", new { argument = "jpg" }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary" })`. There is no need to use javascript.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it works, I didn't need the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reach your controller with

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadAsJPG", "Home")'"
```

and just want to pass some parameters. You can do that same was as

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadAsJPG", "Home", new { argument = "tojpg" })'"
```

or with help of Jquery event

> Edit

Try to wrap your event into `$(document).ready()`. By my experience, most of the time the reason for not working events is a that your buttons is not yet created when event binding happends.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tojpg').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadAsJPG", "Home", new { argument = "tojpg" })';
    });
}
```

And if you dont want to write a separate event for each button option you can create something like this.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="jpg">JPG</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="jpgcmyk">JPG-CMYK</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="jpgrgb">JPG-RGB</button>
```

and Jquery event like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadAsJPG", "Home", new { argument = "'+ $(this).attr("value") +'" })';
    });
}
```

That should work.

Comment: I used the second suggestion. For some reason I cannot get the jquery function fired up. I'm gonna investigate on that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of solving this:

**Option 1**

A `<button />` is not part of the data that the form is posting. That is why it doesn't turn up at the server side. You should change this into an input like so:

`<input type="submit" name="argument" value="jpg" />`

The name of this field should be the same one as the name of the parameter in your action. Because this is an `input`-field, the browser will send the it with the entire post. This is what is being done in the posts you referred to.

**Option 2**

If you want to use `window.location` instead, then you need to make sure the action allows for a GET-request and that you pass in `argument` as the querystring:

`onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadAsJPG", "Home", new { argument = "jpg" })'"`