# How do I submit a "file" input without submit button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, forms, submit

There is a way to automatically submit a form without clicking to a "submit" button?

I have a form with one "file" input. I would submit the form after the user have selected one file.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

yes, you can use the `form.submit()` function. Add an onchange listener on the file input and link it to the `form.submit()` function, like so:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="myFile"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can add the following to the `onchange` event of the file input:

```
<input type='file' .... onchange='this.form.submit();'>
```

this submits the form right after the user has picked a file.
However, the user can't correct a mistaken selection before submitting - be sure to check whether this is really wise.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for me.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/upload">
  <input id="myfilefield" type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```
document.getElementById('myfilefield').onchange = function() {
  this.form.submit();
};
```

By the way, you don't need to use flash. Gmail do it by XHR Level 2.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do this. Browsers are very, very strict about what you can do to file upload fields, because of the potential for abuse. If the user accidentally selects a private file, they wouldn't want it to immediately start uploading that file to a random server.

Comment: not true, I just tested the code in my answer, and it works (at least in Firefox).

Comment: Checked with IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox - none will accept this, while `onchange='alert("test");'` is fine. Believe, this does not work for enctype multipart/form-data - which is required to have a file-upload work.

Comment: edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript That's the point. don't name the submit button `submit`, else it fails with console error `submit is not a function`. name it different, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the restrictions are with doing this in an HTML form.

You can, however, do it with Flash.  Gmail does it - when I click "Attach a file", I get prompted with a file browse dialog, and when I OK that dialog the upload begins immediately, and also gives me a progress bar.

Googling for "Flash uploader" will give you many options, but I don't have experience with any of them.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions that were here to add an event listener in the input didn't work for me, so I found another solution, and I wanted to share it.

HTML:

```
    <form id="attachUpload" method="POST"  action="javascript:void(0)" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="uploadAttachment" type="file" name="files[]" placeholder="Computer" multiple />
</form>
```

The code to submit the form:

```
$(document).on('change', '#uploadAttachment', function() {
$('#attachUpload').trigger('submit');
```

});

And than if you want to post that data after the form is submitted:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#attachUpload', function(e) {
// code here
})
```