# asp.net fileupload control should load without submitting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

In ASP.NET, I am using fileupload control to upload files to my server as everyone. But I have two buttons on my screen, the first one is the filuplooad's button which opens up the "File Selection Screen", the second button is to submit the selected file to upload. I dont want the the second button.

What I want is, I want the user to click the first button, when the user selects the file and closes that screen, I want it to be uploaded automatically. I dont want the user to do the clicking...

How can I do it with javascript or C#?

Comment: I found this code <asp:FileUpload ID="myFileUpload" onchange="if (confirm('Upload ' + this.value + '?')) this.form.submit();" runat="server" />

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I submit a "file" input without submit button with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904168/how-do-i-submit-a-file-input-without-submit-button-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it with [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) control from AjaxControlToolkit.

Looks like this is duplicate question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904168/how-do-i-submit-a-file-input-without-submit-button-with-javascript).

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot use the ajaxcontroltoolkit for some reasons :(