# How do I resolve JavaScript error "not defined"?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, forms

This form works in Safari.  In IE, it mostly works, but I get an error "Object doesn't support this property or method." on line 240.

In Firefox, no alert box appears, but the following error appears in the error console:

Error: myform is not defined
Line: 240 (line 240 is below, starting with the word if)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Validate the form
// Confirm with the visitor the amount he entered is correct
// Submit if OK is pressed
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").validate({
        submitHandler:function(form){
            if(confirm("Please confirm your donation of $"+ myform.x_Amount.value + " to us.")){
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    });
});

// Put grey "no spaces" example text in the credit card number field
$('#x_Card_Num').example('(NoSpaces)', {
  className: 'greydefaulttext'
});
</script>
```

Guess I need to define myform.x_Amount.value.  Have tried doing this in various ways but haven't stumbled across the right location to define it yet, or even the right syntax.  Thanks for any help.

Update: Thanks to fresh eyes from RC and Bobince, it was simply a typo: myform.x_Amount.value should be named form.x_Amount.value - it now works in all browsers.

Comment: what does you script tag look like. This can occur if you make the script tag incorectly.

Comment: Changing it to <script type="text/javascript"> should help

Comment: You shoud try with `form.x_Amount.value` or some jQuery selector

Comment: Yes, is it not just a simple `myform`/`form` typo?

Comment: Yes, RC and Bobince, it was a typo: myform should be form.  Thanks very much for seeing that!  

Now the alert box comes up in all browsers, but I get a new JavaScript error: 

Error: form.submit is not a function
Line: 241

Comment: Is there a way I can give you guys credit for figuring it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "submit is not a function" means that
>   you named your submit button or some
>   other element submit. Rename the
>   button to btnSubmit and your call will
>   magically work.
>
> When you name the button submit, you
>   override the submit() function on the
>   form.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-in-javascript)

that fixes your one error. If by `form.x_Amount.value` you want to get the value of a textfield, try it like this:

```
document.form_name.element_name.value;
```

[tutorial](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html)

Comment: Thank you CJD, this indeed resolved the second error "Error: form.submit is not a function".

Comment: Would also like to give Bobince credit for figuring out the first error "not defined" (it was just a typo).