# javascript submit() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [submit is not a function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-in-javascript)

Why is the following basic javascript function giving me an error `document.getElementById("form").submit is not a function`.

The only thing i have on a page is a form and this javascript function. I want he form to auto submit when page is accessed.

```
<script>
 window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById('form').submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the markup that includes the element with ID: 'form'.

Answer (score 69):

Make sure that there is no `name="submit"` or `id="submit"` in the form

Comment: also make sure there is no `onsumbit="somefunction()"`

Comment: No. that _should_ be ok @AdamM.

Comment: Ok. I came here because of this problem, then I removed my onsubmit and it worked. Now I can't reproduce it anymore hmmm so ye it should be ok as you said.

Comment: @AdamM. your onsubmit was probably doing something that stopped the default action or something (or prevented event bubbling etc)

Comment: I wish there were a better way because lots of people name and id their submit button with "submit".

Answer (score 20):

This is probably because the form contains input with name=submit; then the `submit` property contains object of the element. Rename it or use

```
document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('form'));
```

Comment: Very nice. A lifesaver when working with 3rd party frameworks.