# jQuery submit() will not work for me undefined property?

Tags: jquery, submit

This is what I got:

```
<form method="post" id="myform" class="myform">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return claim();" name="submit" class="onsubmit" value="" />
</form>
```

```js
function claim() {
    var c = confirm('You sure?');

    if (!c) {
        return false;
    }

    var password = prompt("Please mention pw","");
    if (password != null && password != "") {
        $.post(
            "/claim/", 
            { partner_pwd: password },
            function(data) {
                if (data == '1') {
                    $('form').submit(function() {
                        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    }
```

This works well, but my problem is that it won't submit the form. I tried both `$('form').submit()` and `$('#myform').submit()` inside the `data == '1'` statement. I tried `alert(1)` inside this if statement, and it displayed fine, I only need to make it submit the form, why wont this work?

***Update:***

**Console says:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function jquery.min.js:3 f.event.trigger
```

Comment: What if you change your button name to something else, like `name="notsubmit"`?

Comment: http://blog.sourcecoder.net/2009/10/jquery-submit-on-form-element-does-not-work/ might help!

Comment: @Tats_innit The link which helped is not available now. Can you please write here the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made the following mistakes:

1. jQuery selector `'form'` is too general and returns an array. So change it to `'#myform'`.
2. Also your javascript never allows your form to be submitted. The culprit is the last line : `return false;`. Even after successfully validating the form, this line blocked it. It should have been `return true;`. This mistake was pointed out by @11684, but no one understood him and was downvoted by some.

Anyways, here's the debugged code.

```
 function claim()
{
    var c = confirm('You sure?');

    if (!c) {
        return false;
    }

    var password=prompt("Please mention pw","");
    if (password!=null && password!="")
      {
            $.post("/claim/", { partner_pwd: password },
               function(data) {
                    if(data == '1')
                    {
                        $('#myform').bind('submit',function() {
                          alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
                        });
                    }
               });
      }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: ncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function jquery.min.js:3 f.event.trigger

Comment: still not working. Now it submits even when the data is 0 or when you cancel out from prompt()....

Comment: Update: this worked after tats_innit solution in the comment. I had a submit button named submit which did the submit() did not work.

Comment: @Karem The link which helped you is not available now. Can you please write here the solution?

Answer (score 3):

To raise an event, you call the relevent function without a parameter like this:

```
$('form').submit();
```

Your current code is simply adding a submit handler function to be executed when the form is submit, it is not actually submitting the form.

Comment: Wasnt me, but this does not work. Tried and console gives me ncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function jquery.min.js:3 f.event.trigger

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I too didn't downvote. But want to tell you that when "onclick" on a submit button is called, the submit process is already scheduled to begin and there's no need to trigger it again.

Comment: @ahmed that's true, exvept the function ALWAYS returns false. The Ajax success needs to call the submit() manually.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#myform')[0].submit();
```

Comment: jQuery also has `.submit()` method.

Comment: @xdazz: Yep but it is better to use vanilla stuff where possible.

Comment: @Karem: Can you inspect through console what error are you getting what exactly is happenning ?

Comment: In console i get error:  ncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function jquery.min.js:3
f.event.trigger

Answer (score 0):

As Rory said, your code will only add an event handler. You need to do

```
$(form).submit()
```

with no parameters. If you want to attach a handler, and then trigger the event later, you can use

```
$(form).trigger('submit')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem except I was trying to submit the form from Javascript, not attach an onsubmit event handler. The issue turned out to be that the submit button on the form I was working with had its name="submit"...I suspect that was part of what caused the original poster's problem as well. When the form has a button named "submit", it creates a "submit" property on the form object, overwriting the usual value of the "submit" property, which is a function that submits the form.

See [javascript submit() is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525790/javascript-submit-is-not-a-function) for more details