# Submit a form without ID using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form without any ID.

`<form action="LoginServlet" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">`

How can I get the form to submit?

I only have on form on that page, so I tried this but it didn;t work.

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

Comment: _“Didn’t work”_ isn’t a problem description. Any errors in the console?

Comment: more code?i test worked

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. You have an `<input>` with `name="submit"`. [If you don’t rename that button, you can’t use the `submit` function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525790/javascript-submit-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @nitesh if you try to submit the form, it won't work since it has captcha. Submitting programmatically will be difficult since it has captcha.

Comment: @parag I have entered the captcha directly first. I then need to perform the "Login" action. document.getElementById('captcha').value = '\(value)';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,tested ok according to the url you give:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0].click();
```

code below doesn't work because the website have an input whose name is 'submit'

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

so ,when you execute

```
document.forms[0].submit//returns an input element,not a function
```

so,

```
document.forms[0].submit() //doesn't work,cause document.forms[0].submit is not a function
```

Comment: 'document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary')[0].click();' This didn't work too.

Comment: @Nitesh ，this url:passbook.epfindia.gov.in/MemberPassBook/Login.jsp  ?i test worked

Comment: Sorry, It works. Problem now is with the pass text which I set it this way 'document.getElementById('password').value = 'passwordhere';' Can you help me with this? I'm getting error Password not available if I set it by this.

Comment: @Nitesh you set it right,and i test it right,what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was just typo in my code. Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.