# all of commands for submit in onChange select not work

Tags: html

i want to use `onChange()` in `select` but all of this commands not work for me:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" name='testBank' id="testBank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="major_id" id='major_id' onchange="this.submit();">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <?
        $query = mysql_query("select * from at_majors where view='1'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            ?><option value="<? echo $row['major_id']?>" > TEST </option><?
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    </form>
```

**commands**

```
onchange="this.submit()"
onchange="testBank.submit();"
onchange="this.testBank.submit()"
onchange="submit()"
onchange="document.all.submit()"
onchange="document.testBank.submit();"
```

i get this error:

```
this.submit is not a function
```

**important**

i dont like to use jquery or javascript for this method. please help me to repair this problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's your form (simplified a bit for the purposes of the demo):

```
<form name='testBank'>
<select name="major_id" onchange="submitTestBank();">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
</form>
```

And then the most simple JavaScript (referring to the form by its name):

```
function submitTestBank() {
    document.forms.testBank.submit();
}
```

Of course you could just add `document.forms.testBank.submit();` directly to the `onchange` attribute. Having a separate function like `submitTestBank` is more reusable though. It helps if you want to attach a submit handler to multiple `select` or `input` elements.

**[See it in action.](http://jsbin.com/eracut/1/edit)**

Comment: `submit is not a function`

Comment: @TuxWorld Have you tried the link I provided? There's no error. You might be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are trying to submit the `select` tag, not the form.

```
<form method="post" name='testBank' id="testBank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="major_id" id='major_id' onchange="document.getElementById('testBank').submit();">
```

This should work.

#### EDIT

This should also work:

```
<select name="major_id" id='major_id' onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

Comment: thanks. `document.getElementById("testBank").submit is not a function
[Break On This Error]  
document.getElementById("testBank").submit();`

Comment: Uhm, that's weird, i just made a quick test and it's fine. Are you sure you have valid html (doctype and so on)?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<select name="major_id" id='major_id' onchange=this.form.submit();">
```

Comment: this.form.submit is not a function

Comment: oh.. r u get the solution?

Comment: i want ur help for css how can i get?

Answer (score 1):

If the submit input element have name as "submit" the form won't submit. So please remove the submit.

Avoid this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Use This

```
<input type="submit" name="xxx" value="xxx">
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not like to use jQuery, then try this:

```
<select name="major_id" id='major_id' onchange="doSomething(this)">
```

Make sur to define your javascript before the select element:

```
function doSomething(sel) {
    alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value);
}
```