# Input names that should not be used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Earlier, I was creating a form and mindlessly named one of my inputs "name", similar to the following pseudo code:

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
```

I then remembered that in the past, I've had issues with inputs with the name "action." If I remember correctly, the issues arose during enhancement with JavaScript (there was confusion between the form's action and the input with the name "action").

So my questions are:

- Is it safe to use something similar to the snippet above?
- Is there some canonical list of strings that should generally NOT be used as input names?

Comment: if you are using jquery to target them it will probably be ok with any valid name

Comment: I would say avoid common attributes of the form and also the method names that are attached to the form. Common problem is [Submit Is Not A Function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/834197/14104)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's mostly problems if you're using shortcuts like `myform.action` as `action` is a property of the `form` element (like are `id`, `parentNode`, and some other properties you can see using `console.dir(myform)`).

You should always use the fast and reliable way :

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('action');
```

or, using jQuery :

```
var $input = $('#action');
```

As noticed by epascarello, you'll also have problem if you call or use a property that you overrided by defining an element with that name, for example `submit`. But as *you*'re the one calling it in your code, it should be obvious if it happens.

Comment: getElementById is not going to save you 100% of the time. Name an element submit and call the submission via JavaScript. The name will override the method.