# Combine checkbox values into string before submitting form

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I am sending a form to an external server I have limited access to. I have a form with many  check-boxes for different products the user is interested in. I need to send these in a single string that lists all the products they checked.

I know I need to use JavaScript to capture the selections and combine them into one variable and then send it through POST to the external server. I'm not very experienced in Javascript to know how exactly.

Comment: What format does the server expect the data? Just one string of name-value pairs, or is it in JSON format as amsterdam discusses below?

Comment: Actually I am sending it to a SalesForce server so I just need the input names of the checked checkboxes in a comma separated string: "Product A, Product D, Product F". Also, I've never used JSON to POST a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to give you a hint on how to catch up the checked checkboxes once the form is submitted ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uEQVC/11/)).

Imagine you have the following html:

```
<form id="testForm">
    <input class="checkbox" name="one" type="checkbox">
    <input class="checkbox" name="two" type="checkbox">
    <input class="checkbox" name="three" type="checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" name="checkboxStr" id="checkbox_str">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

You can add an event listener to form submission:

```
var form = document.getElementById('testForm');

try {
    form.addEventListener("submit", submitFn, false);
} catch(e) {
    form.attachEvent("onsubmit", submitFn); //IE8
}
```

And then you can get all the needed checkboxes with for example its class name.
Loop trough them and add the checked ones to an array which you later on join to a string.

```
function submitFn(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var checked = [];
    for(var i=0; boxes[i]; ++i){
      if(boxes[i].checked){
        checked.push(boxes[i].name);
      }
    }

    var checkedStr = checked.join();

    document.getElementById('checkbox_str').value = checkedStr;
    form.submit();

    return false;
}
```

You can now send this string via ajax or you can add a hidden form field and set the string as its value and submit the form without ajax.

Comment: I'd perfer `if (form.addEventListener) { ... } else { ... }` over a try-catch block

Comment: Can you explain why? :)

Comment: I'm sure it's a dumb mistake but after much effort I can't get the script to set the value of the hidden field... oyy

Comment: I hope it's not uncouth to post an address, but my page is at www.megadyne.com/new/samples.php to see the code.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Consider how try-catch is implemented and the cost incurred to throw an exception. A primitive if statement is significantly simpler. Also, I prefer using a try-catch for error conditions, and I don't believe that this qualifies as one.

Comment: @BrianBarrus Added example code for the hidden input field solution to my answer. Didn't update the jsfiddle though. To simplify things you may change the submit event handler to a click event handler of the button which will not interfere your manual submission.

Comment: @KshitijMehta Isn't "*undefined function addEventListener*" or whatever happens when in IE8 an error?

Comment: Note: if you get a "Submit is not a function error", you may need to remove any name attribute from your submit button for this to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript

Comment: want to convert it into string directly with a seperator                var str;             if(boxes[i].checked){
                        str +=   boxes[i].value+'|';
}

Answer (score 1):

First you need to grab the name value pairs and store them to an object as such:

```
var obj = {}; // this will hold your name value pairs
```

From there you can use JSON to send the data to the server.  JSON data is in string form when it is sent to the server.

```
var json_string = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain how to grab the name-value pairs. He says he's not experienced

Comment: (interrupting) Pardon me sir.