# Cannot programmatically submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-forms

Cannot get my form to submit programmatically, despite trying several ways. Tried pure JS, also tried jQuery. No success.

I have this form tag :

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13zex8ZsEsnZz3A8uB4jU4oDb5wZfaqqq2Pq2CGlIe6M/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_self" onsubmit="" name="eForm">
    <!--My Form Stuff-->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit">
</form>
```

Here is what i've tried :

```
/*jQuery*/
$('#ss-form').submit();

/*Javascript*/
document.getElementById('ss-form').submit();
document.eForm.submit();
```

None of them work. Not sure why, but I am assuming it has something to do with me trying to submit a google form. If I physically click the submit everything works fine.

Any and all help is greatly apprecaiated.

Comment: Maybe you have more JS which causes a problem? Do you see any errors ?

Comment: @putvande no console errors. Everything else is working fine.

Comment: Is your form loaded on the page when you try to submit it?

Comment: @Adjit out of curiosity, can you use one of those lines you proposed in the console?

Comment: @DaveNewton nothing. Doesn't give me an error, or anything. Its as if the function isn't there.

Comment: @IonicãBizãu yes, the form is loaded. Currently using jQuery `$(document).ready()` also tried `(function(){})()`

Comment: Where is the submission code? Is it in an event handler? If you check the Network tab of DevTools, do you see any mention of submitting the form? I also wonder about `onsubmit=""` -- does removing that change anything?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/LZkAj/

Comment: @IonicãBizãu added a live example

Comment: Cannot reproduce neither... http://jsfiddle.net/D7eP9/

Comment: I am not seeing the responses though...

Comment: @IonicãBizãu what are you using to submit? when I try to even submit through the console it gives my a type error saying an object is not a function

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just put this script out of the head, at the end of body...

Comment: @FlashThunder thats not the issue. I am trying to submit the form as soon as the page loads

Comment: @Barmar don't see any mention of form submission. Also, took out `onsubmit`... no dice.

Comment: @esqew I get type errors saying an object is not a function when I try to submit with the console

Comment: @Adjit Maybe it's a browser issue. I posted an answer.

Comment: This is because your `submit input` name is `submit` ... and it is restricted name that overrides `form.submit()` function... just rename it to something else like `submiter` and it will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you have a field (`HTMLInputElement`) with name `submit` in the form. That's why `document.getElementById('ss-form').submit`  is not a function but an object.

So, you get the following error:

> `TypeError: object is not a function`

The solution is to remove that element. We should be careful to verify if browser thinks it's an element and not a function:

```
if (typeof document.getElementById('ss-form').submit === "object") {
    document.getElementById('ss-form').submit.remove();
}
document.getElementById('ss-form').submit();
```

Comment: Nailed it! I thought I had checked that... because I recall seeing that issue elsewhere. Needless to say, thanks for all the help... spent way too long scratching my head on this one.

Comment: Cool, take a look at this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/833032/1420197

Comment: Thats exactly where I saw it when I was looking how to programmatically submit a form. Don't know why I didn't realize it sooner.