# Why am I getting error: TypeError: "_co.form.submit is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I'm trying to implement a Reactive Form that only submits when the submit button is clicked, not when the user hits `Enter` in an `Input`, but I'm getting `TypeError: "_co.form.submit is not a function"` and saw many similar questions such as [submit is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript) and [can't programmatically submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370355/cannot-programmatically-submit-form?noredirect=1&lq=1), but none of the solutions worked (such as making sure the button is not named "submit"). I even made a small test app (code shown at bottom) which works fine, so I'm perplexed why my original app is having problems. The obvious difference between the code that works and doesn't work is that in the code that works I have `#form` template reference variable, but I took that out in the code that's having problems because including `#form` cause even more problems, such as `TypeError: "this.form.get is not a function"` and the form won't even render with `#form` in the element, whereas without it, at least the form renders even if it won't submit.

Here are excerpts from the code that is having problems:

`details.component.html`

```
<form class="member-wrapper" [formGroup]="form" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/users/{{route}}/details">
  <div class="member-header">
    <h3 class="member-title">{{(updating) ? 'Please update your details' : 'Share a bit about yourself'}}</h3>
    <h4 class="member-description">Description</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="member-body">
    . . . 
    . . . 
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="form.submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`details.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, ElementRef, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { TagDirective} from '../tag.directive';
. . . 
. . . 

export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChildren(TagDirective) ipt!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  got_data: boolean = false; 
  first_pass: boolean = true; updating: boolean = false; 
  data: Object;
  meta: Object;
  data_string: string;
  datArr: any[] = [];
  formCtls: any = {};

. . . 
. . .
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
. . . 
. . . 


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
. . . 
. . . 
  ],
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
. . . 
. . . 
  ],
```

`details.module.ts` (feature module for details component)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TagDirective } from '../tag.directive';

import { DetailsRoutingModule } from './details-routing.module';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DetailsComponent, TagDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DetailsRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class DetailsModule { }
```

Here is the small test code that works fine:

`test.component.html`

```
<form #form [formGroup]="form" METHOD="GET" action="http://localhost:3000/test">
  <input placeholder="Enter" formControlName="input1"/>
  <input placeholder="The Dragon" formControlName="input2"/>
  <button type="button" (click)="form.submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`test.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Many thanks in advance if any ideas why I'm getting this error!

Comment: Try using a different name for your template reference variable instead of `form` because you have 2 things with the same name `form` in the same scope so there is some ambiguity

Comment: according to [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) a `FormGroup` has no submit function - perhaps you're using the wrong angular object

Comment: I tried using different names for template reference variable, but that didn't fix it. And also, in my small test code that works, the template reference variable and FormGroup have the same name, and the code still works. I'm really befuddled! Any further ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This line of code here is wrong

```
  <button type="button" (click)="form.submit()">Submit</button>
```

This is how you can submit using reactive form using `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"`

Example

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="UserName">Your email</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="UserName"
        name="UserName"
        required
        formControlName="UserName"
      />
      <div
        *ngIf="UserName.invalid && (UserName.dirty || UserName.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger"
      >
        <div *ngIf="UserName.errors.required">
          Email is required
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="UserName.errors.whitespace">
          whitespace is required
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Your password</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        ngModel
        class="form-control"
        id="Password"
        name="Password"
        required
        formControlName="Password"
      />
      <div
        *ngIf="Password.invalid && (Password.dirty || Password.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger"
      >
        <div *ngIf="Password.errors.required">
          Password is required
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Many thanks, and much appreciated. I've edited my question to make clear that I'm trying to have the form submit only on button click, and doesn't submit when the user hits `Enter` in one of the `Input` elements. Also, even after making the changes in your answer, I still get `TypeError: "_co.onSubmit is not a function"`. There must be something wrong with my declarations or imports, but I can't figure out what. And more confusing to me is that the small sample code I included works fine. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'd be delighted to share the code. I'm fairly new to GitHub and my head is spinning a bit trying to figure out how to make the code public without letting others change my original code. (So anyone can fork my code, but not edit the original). Is that default behavior, or do I need to do something to enable that?

Comment: Separately, it seems @Teedeez was right after all, as I fixed the problem by changing `#form` to `#myform` and `form.submit()` to `myform.submit()`. I don't know why my simple test code worked previously with `#form`. I surmise it must have had silent errors but was still able to submit, while my more detailed code failed on those errors.