# Console not printing contents of input field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have my console print the contents of an `input` field with a `type` of `file`.  However, it's not doing this.  It's actually behaving as though a form is being submitted, although there is no action attached to the form at this time.  Can anyone explain why I'm unable to get the value of the desired field?

**js**

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    var image = $("#dept_image").val();
    console.log(image);
})
```

**html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="departments" class="view">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="dept_name">Department Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="dept_name" id="dept_name" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="dept_image">Image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="dept_image" id="dept_image" />
    </fieldset>
    <button name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to prevent default behaviour of submit button. And you must change name attribute of submit button to something different than `submit`

Comment: @A.Wolff Why must it be changed?

Comment: Crap, that's a typo.  I've fixed it.

Comment: BTW, to get files of input file, use property `files` of DOM node, not value

Comment: @Scimonster Because of this e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-in-javascript

Comment: @A.Wolff So instead of using `.val`, use `.files`?

Comment: @Robert you can use: `$("#dept_image").get(0).files` or `$("#dept_image")[0].files` or `document.getElementById('dept_image').files` or `$("#dept_image").prop("files")`

Comment: When I do that, I get the console log of `FileList[File]`.  How do I see the path text?

Comment: JavaScript does not have access to the file's path. What are you needing it for @Robert?

Comment: Ah, so there's really no way for me to see the path text?

Comment: @Robert for security reason, in js no

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default action by capturing the event and acting on it -

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action of the submit
    var image = $("#dept_image").val();
    console.log(image);
})
```

Nothing will be console logged from the submitting page because you are 'leaving' it to load a 'new' page (even though it is itself). Now you can ad AJAX to the function to do whatever submission action you would care to.