# Progress image loader in pure javascript Only when user clicks on submit html form

Tags: javascript, html, image, loader

I'd like to show a `progress image loader` only when the user clicks on `submit` on my html form but at the moment the `progress image loader` is displayed also when the user `reloads` the page... so I'd like to isolate the event only a clicked button `(submit)` without having the `progress image loader` displayed when the user `reloads` the page. I provide an example in order to show what I looking for in pure javascript.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>BackUp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="backup.css">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function StartProgress() {
    ProgressImage = document.getElementById('progress_image');
    document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout("ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src", 100);
    return true;
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body onUnload="StartProgress()">

<div class="mainbox">
  <div class="box1">
    <span class="title">BackUp</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cleardiv"></div>
  <div class="box2">
    <form onSubmit="return StartProgress()" action="backup.php" method="post">
    <input class="backup_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="BackUp">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="cleardiv"></div>
  <div style="display: none" id="progress"><img id="progress_image" src="css/busy.gif" alt="BackUp in progress..."></div>
  <div class="cleardiv"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

change your form to be something like this:

```
<form id='form1' action="backup.php" method="post">
    <input type='button' onclick='submitForm()' value="BackUp" />
</form>
```

submitForm function:

```
function submitForm() {
    StartProgress();
    var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
    form1.submit();
    //setTimeout(function(){
    //  form1.submit();
    //}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function SubmitForm() {
    StartProgress();
    var backup = document.getElementById("backup");
    backup.submit();
  }
  function StartProgress() {
    ProgressImage = document.getElementById('progress_image');
    document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout("ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src", 100);
    return true;
  }
  </script>` I get backup.submit is not a function... where is wrong?

Comment: your code works but I get javascript error backup.submit is not a function... how to solve this issue?

Comment: `<form id="backup" action="backup.php" method="post">
<input class="backup" type="submit" name="backup" onclick="SubmitForm()" value="BackUp">
</form>` changing the name of input did solve the problem... thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript