# Use href to submit into a php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a login form which  should provide 2 ways to submit , one through the login button which should submit the info into the login.php and another through the href (Forgot password) which should redirect the user and submit the info to the forgotpassword.php file. So far I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function  forgotpassword()
{

document.getElementById("ee").action="project_forgotpassword.php";
document.getElementById("ee").submit();

}    
</script>
<form id="ee" method="POST" action="login.php">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<th>Password</th>
<td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><a href="project_forgotpassword.php" onClick="javascript:  forgotpassword();">Forgot Password</a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>   
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your function name be `project_forgotpassword`?

Comment: It should indeed, sorry for the typo... but still it is not working

Comment: you can lose the `javascript:` from the `onclick` handler

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 1):

- First issue as I have commented was the typo mistake.
- Second issue is submit button name. Refer to following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dtsxtzb/)

#### Code

```js
function forgotpassword() {
  var form = document.getElementById("ee");
  form.action = "project_forgotpassword.php";
  console.log(form)
  form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="ee" method="POST" action="login.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="username">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Password</th>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="password">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="project_forgotpassword.php" onClick="javascript:  forgotpassword();">Forgot Password</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

#### Changes

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Now it submits fine, but the problem is that when I try to refer to the username tag value by $username=$_POST['username']; it says that the username is undefined index.

Comment: My apologies! I dont know PHP, but are you getting values on submit button?

Comment: yes but my point is that, I also want to get the values from href that is what  I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the javascript function you can omit the `javascript:` from the `onclick` handler. You might wish to use that syntax when invoking the function from a standard hyperlink, such as `<a href='javascript:func()'>link</a>` but that is not common.

In the amended `forgotpassword` function I use `setAttribute` rather than trying to call the attribute directly - I think it is more reliable that way. Also, unless in the js function, you prevent the default action of the hyperlink it will simply try to go to the value in the href attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    function forgotpassword(){
        document.getElementById("ee").action="project_forgotpassword.php";
        document.getElementById("ee").submit();
    }
    */

    /* I would tend to use this approach to setting an attribute */
    function forgotpassword(){
        var form=document.getElementById("ee");
        form.setAttribute('action','project_forgotpassword.php');
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
<form id="ee" method="POST" action="login.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <th>Password</th>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="#" onclick="forgotpassword()">Forgot Password</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="subform" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
</form>
```

One final thing - change the name of the submit button ~ it shouldn't be called `submit` - especially when trying to invoke form submission using javascript.

Comment: Can you explain a bit, what you have changed and what was issue?

Comment: I tried the cod but it says member not found in the line :  document.getElementById("ee").submit();

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#forgetpassword').click(function(){

      $("form[name='form_name']").attr("action", "project_forgotpassword.php");      

      $("form[name='form_name']").submit();
   });
```

Change the forget Password link as below,

```
<a id="forgetpassword">Forgot Password</a>
```