# jQuery submit button on another button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a submit on my page:

```
<input type=​"submit" name=​"nextstep" value=​"Next" id=​"nextstep" class=​"newaddressnextstepbutton">​
```

and when I click on this submit I need to make another submit on first button with specific name like this:

```
<input type="button" name="selectBillingAddress" value="First one" class="selectbillingaddressbutton" onclick="setLocation('/checkout/selectbillingaddress?addressId=537')">
<input type="button" name="selectBillingAddress" value="Second one" class="selectbillingaddressbutton" onclick="setLocation('/checkout/selectbillingaddress?addressId=647')">
```

I did it like this:

```
$("input[name='nextstep']").click(function() {
        $("input[name='selectBillingAddress']")[0].submit();
});
```

But this not working. I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function`
I found this answer for this error ["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript) but I dont have `input[name='submit']` on this page..

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I think I finally figured out your intent and posted some suggestions below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the submit function on the form, not the button.
So it should be something like this:

```
  $("input[name='nextstep']").click(function() {
       $("form").submit();
  });
```

If you have more than one form on your page give your form an ID and use that instead.

Comment: This is not doing what the OP wanted. The other buttons are changing the URL when clicked. Not submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

`.submit()` is only available on `form` elements.

Instead you need to trigger a native click event on the first matching DOM element instead:

e.g.

```
$("#nextstep").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("[name='selectBillingAddress']")[0].click();
});
```

### Notes:

- You should target the element using an id selector is available (faster/shorter)
- As a good practice, you should prevent the original click event from submitting the form, and not just assume the redirect will override it.
- You need to use `.click()` on the DOM element to call the native click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry: Here is the UPDATED one.

```
$("input[name='nextstep']").click(function() {
        $("input[name='selectBillingAddress']").eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: You are incorrectly getting the DOM element with [0] and calling `trigger` on that (which does not exist).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Just Updated.

Comment: This will not work as jQuery trigger wont fire the inline `onclick` event. You need to hit the native click handler like @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Answer (score -1):

Try to invoke the natural click of the button,

```
$("input[name='nextstep']").click(function() {
     $("input[name='selectBillingAddress']")[0].click();
});
```

Or just grab the closest form and invoke `.submit()` over it. Since elements other than form will not have submit function as its member.

Comment: Mr.Brilliance, Please tell us why did you cast a down vote to this answer?