# PHP JavaScript uncaught error with onchange

Tags: javascript, php, onchange, typeerror

I have dropdown list and when somebody chooses something I need to submit it, here's my code:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <body bgcolor="#E2E2E2">
       <form action='index.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'    id='myform'>
     <div div style="position: absolute;left: 35%; top: 30%;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
      <?php
     include ("config.php");
     // Create connection
  //form start

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


 // output data of each row
 echo"<tr><td>формат: ";

       echo"<select class='format' name='formater'onchange='document.getElementById('myform').submit()'>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<option value='". $row["$formatPrice"]. "'>".$row["$formatColumn"]. "</option>";
 }

  }
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     echo "aaa";
  }
 ?>
```

When i choose option that error comes out: ***Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function  onchange***
Thanks for any help.

Here is rendered html:

```
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head><body bgcolor="#E2E2E2">
    <form action="client.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
     <div div="" style="position: absolute;left: 35%; top: 30%;">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
    <table border="1px" class="table"><tbody><tr><td>Calculator </td></tr>        <tr><td>ფორმატი: <select class="format" name="formater" onchange="document.getElementById(" myform').submit()'=""><option   value="0.15">A3</option><option value="0.1">A4</option><option value="0.05">A5</option><option value="0.035">A4/3</option>aaa</select></td>        </tr><tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"></td> </tr>


  </tbody></table></div></form></body></html>
```

So after marking this question as duplicate, Quentin showed me this link ["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript) 
and yes, its absolutely another thing, these answers didn't help me, I think its more in PHP than in js, because i tried this code without PHP and it worked... Now I am becoming more confused with this!

Comment: Might not be the cause of your error, but you are not closing your select tag, does closing it solve your problem?

Comment: @Stijn actually i close it, its small part of my code, and i dont think that can be problem anywhere

Comment: Could you show us the generated output instead of the php?

Comment: @Stijn ah ok. if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "aaa";
}

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, the form gets submitted when using onchange='this.form.submit()', which browser are you using and are there are no other elements on the page which are causing this problem?

Comment: As Stijn suggested, since this is a client-side error, it would be helpful to see the _rendered_ HTML

Comment: I use google chrome, but I have another submit button in the end, i don't think it can cause any problems

Comment: As suggested by others, show us the HTML that this PHP outputs.

Comment: onchange='document.getElementById('myform').submit()' will not work btw, because the onchange attribute will be closed after: getElementById(, mix the single and double quotes and use \ to escape: echo "<select class='format' name='formater' onchange=\"document.getElementById('myform').submit()\">";

Comment: @Stijn yes i added rendered code

Comment: Your quotes are a mess, as mentioned in my comment above, make sure all the attributes open and close at the correct place. Mix double quotes and single quotes in your HTML / javascript. I usually use double quotes in PHP, escape double quotes with a slash in HTML and use single quotes in javascript:

echo "<button onclick=\"alert('hello');\">click</button>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give the form an ID to make it easier to identify it

```
<form action='index.php' method='post' id='myform' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

then use this for your onchange event

```
onchange='document.getElementById("myform").submit()'
```

I'm not sure if there is something with your formatting. Try...

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
echo "<select class=\"format\" name=\"formater\" onchange=\"document.getElementById('myform').submit()\">";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row['$formatPrice'] . "\">" . $row['$formatColumn'] . "\"</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it is not working!

Comment: I built this example and it works. https://jsfiddle.net/00py82yL/#&togetherjs=GMg7ysagDL

Comment: i am totally confused

Comment: i will update my post

Comment: I have updated my answer with slightly more readable php. Maybe that was the problem?

Comment: no it was not problem.