# How to perform postback operation in ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: asp.net

I want to perform a postback to get data, when the `<div id="roomTypeContainer">` is clicked.
So, wrapped it inside a `LinkButton`. When I click on the `div`, there is an error in the browser console.

> Uncaught TypeError: theForm.submit is not a function

The repeater is in a user control

**ascx:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpRoomTypes" runat="server" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item"
 OnItemDataBound="rpRoomTypes_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rpRoomTypes_ItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <sc:EditFrame ID="efRoomType" runat="server" >
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRoomType" runat="server" CommandName="cmd_RoomType">
       <div id="roomTypeContainer" runat="server">
          ..some html
       </div> 
      </asp:LinkButton>
    </sc:EditFrame>
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

**UPDATE:**
When I click the error link in browser console, this code is shown in console:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['mainform'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.mainform;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit(); //error here
    }
}
</script>
```

The above code seems to be generated by Sitecore. `mainform` is the id of  form in aspx page.

Ran the same script in console and here is the result
[image]

Comment: Check name of your form. It should be unique. If some element on page have same name as your form then this error could appear.

Comment: The master page(aspx) has the form tag with id 'mainform'. This Usercontrol does not have any forms

Comment: Can you post the block of code where theForm.submit is being called?

Comment: Are you able to debug the javascript in your browser so you can get to the point of code that is throwing your error? It is likely source code in the page markup generated by .NET

Comment: Add consoloe.log(theForm) before error and check what you will see

Comment: you can copy this script, modify and run in console

Comment: I executed the script and also `theForm` to see if it was valid. Plz see the pic.

Comment: Check out main layout aspx page, whatever you have set it as, and check the id set on the form element is like so: `<form runat="server" id="mainForm">`. If it is called something else then rename it.

Comment: If you try this in another browser (Firefox/Chrome/IE) does it work?

Comment: The issue appears in any browser.

Comment: Is it possible to reach this page online?

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk.Sorry no, this is not available.

Comment: Try `console.log(theForm.submit)` to be sure that it returns a function

Comment: What @Taleeb wrote. Maybe you are mistakenly assigning something that is not a function to `theForm.submit` in some other script on the page..?

Comment: Does any other element named as `submit` in your page?

Comment: @Qwerty I think you should launch your page locally and then in browser see generated source code of you page for something like id="submit". If that exist just rename that element in your code and then the submit function will work again.

Comment: In your browser's Developer Tools, put a breakpoint on the `theForm.submit();` line. Add a watch for `theForm` and `theForm.submit` (without parentheses), and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this line in the generated JS:

```
var theForm = document.forms['mainform'];
```

theForm is a global variable set at page load, but I wonder if the form element is not yet created at that time (or comes after the script block - that would cause the issue too).  Then, when the function runs in the doPostback, theForm.submit function will not exist since, even though the form is now in existence, the variable referencing it is still null.

In the console, just type theForm and press enter (without assigning it in the console) and see what it is set to.  If it's null/undefined, then that's what's happening, in which case more info is needed to diagnose the failure (for example, why is the form not yet created).

Comment: This would be my guess as well the form might not exist yet at the time the javascript is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use name="mainform" instead of id="mainform"
document.forms['something'] works using name, but not id

Comment: It's the same even with `name=mainform`

Comment: Do you have <form  name='mainform' ...> ? But still document.forms['mainform'].submit() in console return 'not a function'?

Comment: Yes that is right. It still shows the same error as in question

Answer (score 0):

["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript)

> "submit is not a function" means that you named your submit button or
>   some other element submit. Rename the button to btnSubmit and your
>   call will magically work.
>
> When you name the button submit, you override the submit() function on
>   the form.

Make sure that there is no name="submit" or id="submit" in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show browser HTML code generated by your repeater? I suspect that your UserControl  `sc:EditFrame`  generates iframe and your LinkButton works in context of a document loaded into this iframe (which doesn't contain form).

Answer (score 0):

the `form.onSubmit` is an event listener for the submit event, if no handler is set during execution then `form.onsubmit()` will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is pretty vague. Why do you want to put a div inside a LinkButton and that too within a repeater? Is it even clickable? Have you tested with an alert on click of the div?

Also please post the rpRoomTypes_ItemDataBound and the rpRoomTypes_ItemCommand methods.