# Single button for uploading-submitting file - autosubmit file on change. JQuery

Tags: jquery, upload

I want the upload button (that will be hidden) to automatically work out as soon as file is selected(on change). The problem is that I get following error messege. I searched for it and there was an advice to change the name of the button but it didnt help. Here is the error: videator.php:380 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function

jQuery:

```
  $(".upload").click(function(){
      $("#fileToUpload").click();
  });
  document.getElementById("fileToUpload").onchange = submitAction;

   function submitAction(){
       document.getElementById("btnSubmit").submit();
       return false;
   }
```

HTML

```
<form action="videator.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id='btnSubmit'>
       <h3> Select a video to upload:</h3>
       <img class='upload' src="img/upload.png"/>
       <input class="form" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="video/*" >
       <input class="form" id='' type="submit"  value="Upload Image"  name="submit">
   </form>
```

What am I doing wrong? So again: I need a single button instead of 2 buttons (default) . So you click on it and upload-file window pops up - you select a file and it gets uploaded automatically.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following what was said here:

["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript)

You have a submit input named "submit".

```
<input class="form" id='' type="submit"  value="Upload Image"  name="submit">
```

This is what's causing the error to be thrown.  If you rename that button to anything else it should work.

```
<input class="form" id='' type="submit"  value="Upload Image"  name="newName">
```

Here's a working example.  If you open up the console you'll see your `submit` error is gone.

https://jsfiddle.net/mewcg3zo/5/