# "Element is not clickable at point (x,y)". Invisible element covers the button

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I’m stuck trying to get Selenium with Chrome Webdriver to click a buttom, but there is an element `<div class="modal-overlay" style="display: block;"></div>` that covers the entire page and is invisble, that is blocking my clicks. How can I work around this?

I tried using this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

but it didn’t work. What can I do in this situation?
EDIT: 
I used luke_aus answer and got this from the page: (third last image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/loagC.jpg

Comment: Could you tell me when this model overlay visible and when invisible??

Comment: And what do you mean didn't work using `execute_script`??? Is there any exception or anything else??

Comment: No exception, the code continues and the next line fails because its looking at an element that doesnt exist yet (because the buttom wasnt clicked). I'll will upload a couple of screenshots to show the overlay, but basically the only moment when its "visible" is when Im about to click the buttom I want

Comment: screnshots uploaded

Comment: You mean the overlay visible when you goes to click on submit button by mouse over otherwise invisible???

Comment: The overlay is always invisible, until I click the delete ad buttom, which causes the form in the screenshot to pop up. In order to delete a post, I must confirm it in the form. Only when the form is up, is when the overlay is visible.

Comment: So before clicking on submit button you should wait for invisibility of overlay

Comment: But overlay was coded for it to be intentionally visible when the form is up.  I can't wait untill its invisible again, for it will be visible as long as I dont click the form (while at the same time preventing me from clicking the form)

Comment: So do you want to forcefully invisible this overlay before click on submit button??

Comment: that would be a nice solution, since submitting the form via injected javascript (luke_aus's answer) didn't worked.

Comment: Ok I have provided it as an answer try it and let me know...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to make overlay element invisible forcefully before going to click on submit button as below :-

```
#first make overlay element invisible 
overlay = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.modal-overlay")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none'", overlay)

#now find submit button and click 
driver.find_element_by_id("DeleteSurveyO‌​K").click()
```

**Edited1** :- If still it throws exception that submit button is invisible, you should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until submit button visible after overlay element invisible as below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#first make overlay element invisible 
overlay = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.modal-overlay")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none'", overlay)

#now find submit button and click 
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "DeleteSurveyO‌​K")))
button.click()
```

**Edited2** :- If unfortunately submit button is not getting visible try to submit form instead of clicking submit button as below :-

```
#first make overlay element invisible 
overlay = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.modal-overlay")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none'", overlay)

#now submit the form 
driver.find_element‌​_by_id("ModelSurveyFo‌​rm").submit()
```

Comment: The overlay truly becomes invisible again, so that part worked wonderfully. But im getting the following errors: 

when using: " driver.find_element_by_id("DeleteSurvey")"  I get this error: 

    driver.find_element_by_id("DeleteSurveyO\u200c\u200bK").click()

and when using: "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='DeleteSurveyOK']​").click()"

I get: " Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id='DeleteSurveyOK']\u200b' is not a valid XPath expression." Any idea of why its adding the extra '\u200b' that causes the error?

Comment: Why are you going to find element using xpath if could be simply find by I'd as answer provided...use `find_element_by_id` instead and let me know...

Comment: I did. In my first run I used:  driver.find_element_‌​by_id("DeleteSurvey")‌​

and it returned the folllowing error:

"  File "KijijiAutoPosting.py", line 119, in reposting
    driver.find_element_by_id("DeleteSurveyO\u200c\u200bK").click() ...

...     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element"

Comment: for reasons that go beyond me, it decided to add some zero witdh space that makes selenium unable to find the element

Comment: Why append extra char in between I'd as `DeleteSurveyO\‌​u200c\u200bK`??? Please copy the correct I'd from page and pass it...

Comment: You are just providing partial id as `DeleteSurvey‌` which is wrong..`find_element_by_id` find element by exact matching of provided Id so you need to provide exact correct I'd..

Comment: I did NOT append any extra characters. I think it was some weird formatting going in my text editor. I fixed it by writting it by hand, instead of pasting your version, and I get this exeption:

"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible"

Comment: Hmm now this is the right exception...now you should implement `WebdriverWait` to wait until it's visible after overlay invisible before click...

Comment: Ya I have edited my answer..try with it and let me know...:)

Comment: I got this: 
"raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
"

Comment: Ok try once `driver.find_element_by_id("ModelSurveyForm").submit()` and let me know...

Comment: @Silver try to submit form instead of clicking submit button...try second edited answer and let me know..:)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `execute_script` to submit the form

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('myForm').submit()");
```

Comment: I got this error: 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function

Comment: @Silver You did use the _actual_ selector for the form, right?

Comment: oops - just use single quotes...fixed

Comment: this is what I used:
 driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('DeleteSurveyOK').click()")

Comment: use .submit() not .click()

Comment: using submit() I get the:
"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function" error

Comment: that should work. This could be the problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/834197/3003438

Comment: So, I used your code, but the page showed me a "oops, something happened error" and they did not tell me the error. Clicking the element normally shows no problem. Im starting to think that the buttom is intentionally hard to click

Comment: @Silver the actual error says "oops, something happened"?  - where are you seeing this?

Comment: see the pictures in the link under the edit of my post. Also, I was able to do it already =) thanks for the help anyway