# Why does a HTML form not send with the name="submit" and type="submit" using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I was just adding using the JQuery `.submit()` to send off a HTML form to the server. I noticed that when I set `name="submit"` it fails to send the form. When I change the name to something other than `"submit"`, it sends!

This does not work:

```
<form class="edit_a_leaver" action="editLeaver" method="post" hidden>
    <input class="leaver_id" name="leaver_id" type="text">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This does work:

```
<form class="edit_a_leaver" action="editLeaver" method="post" hidden>
    <input class="leaver_id" name="leaver_id" type="text">
    <input name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".edit_a_leaver").submit();
```

Can someone explain to me why? I have tried searching.

Comment: why are you using an input field for submitting a form, it can simply be done by a `<button>`. Any particular reason?

Comment: Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/834197/2798643

Comment: Did you try this without jQuery? AFAIK this is not related to JavaScript or jQuery, but only to HTML and forms.

Comment: Did your read the posts in the link that i provided below ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having issues because the `name` being `submit` is overriding the `form.submit()` function reference for that `<form>`, instead `submit_button.submit` refers to that button, rather than the DOM `submit()` function.

Read [this post](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4652) for more and also this doesn't work even when dhe id is `submit` .

Read [here for this also](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1414)

Answer (score 1):

This is 'intentional'

When you have a form, you can select an element of the form through

```
<form id="form" action="url">
    <input type="text" id="inputId" name="textboxname">
</form>

// Grabbing the input
form.inputId; // that's the input, you can use it in JS
```

But the issue is that this conflicts when the id or name is "action" or "submit", since you'd use `form.submit();`

If you still want to keep the id "submit", you can use the form prototype as such :

> HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form);

Source : https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/dont-name-inputs-action-submit/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the prototype workaround. Just spent a few hours debugging this issue, complex form and of course the button at end was the last thing I checked! Only happened when trying to submit a **clone** of the form. Lesson to when in doubt, steer clear of reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(".edit_a_leaver").submit((function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
});
```