# Avoid multiple onload submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, onload

I'm trying to use function `onload="submit()"` on my form, but when the page loads, it does it multiple times. The result is there, but how can I stop the loop? How can I use it only once? Here's my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("submitted")) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("submitted", "true");
        document.post.submit();
    }
}
    </script>

    <body onload="submit()">
        <form method="post" id="post" name="post">
              //stuff here
             <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Valider" name="test" class="submit">
        </form>
```

Is there anything i'm doing wrong? Or there's any better way to make it?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Is it looping? Submitting is reloading the page, which is kicking off the onload function again ?

Comment: Yes, It's looping by itself, at the first load page.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? `onload` is a function to run when the page loads. It submits the form, which reloads the page, which then runs the `onload` function again.

Comment: So how can i submit my form at the first loading page only without doing it multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sessionStorage` to remember if you've already submitted the form, so you don't do it again.

```
function submit() {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("submitted")) {
        console.log("submitting");
        sessionStorage.setItem("submitted", "true");
        document.getElementById("post").submit();
    } else {
        console.log("already submitted, not repeating");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("submitted");
    }
}
```

Also, don't use `name="submit"` and `id="submit"` for the submit button. See ["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-in-javascript)

Comment: So i just have to replace the other function? it doesn't submit the form

Comment: Change the name of the submit button.

Comment: I changed what you told me, you can see on my first post and it doesn't loop anymore, but doesn't submit my form

Comment: Sorry, `sessionStorage.get` should have been `sessionStorage.getItem`

Comment: I modified it and i don't have any error. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I've added some logging, which log message does it print?

Comment: Delete the item from session storage using Developer Tools and try again. It probably got set during one of the bad attempts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142933/discussion-between-c-jenkins-and-barmar).