# document.getElementById("myForm").submit() is not working

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

```
    <form name="formName" id="formName" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="text1" id="text1" value='0' />
        <input  type="button" name ="submit" onClick="Submit()"  value="submit">
    </form>`
 <script>  
    function Submit() //my function
    {
        document.getElementById("formName").submit();
    }
</script>
I need some help... I have also tried `this document.formName.submit();` but still not working.
```

on debugging i got this error :Uncaught ReferenceError: ***formNameis not defined***

Comment: Change `name="submit"` to a different name.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript code goes into a `<script>` tag, otherwise it is just rendered as text and is not interpreted as code.

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="text1" id="text1" value='0' />
    <input  type="button" name ="submit" onClick="Submit()"  value="submit">
</form>`

<script>
    function Submit() //my function
    {
        document.getElementById("formName").submit();
    }
</script>
```

JavaScript is also case sensitive so "Submit" is not the same as "submit".

And you should never name a form input "submit", read: ["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript).

Comment: then what to do,can you give me solution for it???

Comment: Please explain clearly what you want to achieve. Put more details in your question (not comments).

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code isn’t in  tag. What you are going to do is taging  and put your code between tags.

```
<script>
   Put Your codes here
</script>
```

And change submit() to Submit() in onClick