# Angular 5, iziModal with iframe is not closable from angular component function

Tags: jquery, angular, plugins

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pyrh.png)I am using iziModal([Link](http://izimodal.dolce.ninja/)) for iFrame Modal, i am able to launch the modal, but on closing the modal, the iziModal function is not called. I tried initiating the function in ngviewinit, but still getting the error,

---

[Attached screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgwSN.png)
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).iziModal is not a function
    at :1:21

---

Please somebody help on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript)

Comment: If it is used in angular 2+, the function written inside onClosed, doesnt work, Use onClosing to close the iframe modal