# Make hyperlink a form submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, submit

I am trying to get a hyperlink element to act as a form submit button.  This sort of question has been answered multiple times over the years but, for some reason, I am not able to get it to work even with cut-n-pasted code and I'm wondering if I'm missing something trivially simple that my eyes are too bugged out to see.  The full code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function signup() {
    alert("Form is " + document.signup_form);
    document.signup_form.submit() ;
}
-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <?php
    echo("Submit is [" . $_POST['submit'] . "]");
  ?>

  <form method="post" name="signup_form" id="signup_form" action="" >
    <input type="text" name="from_email" placeholder="e-mail address"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email"> 
    <a href="javascript:signup()">Sign Up!</a><br>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The input submit element ("Send Email") works fine.  The hyperlink ("Sign Up!") also works fine and calls the javascript function so that the alert() box in the function shows up.

So, it's just the `submit()` call that's not doing anything--I even printed out `document.signup_form` in an `alert()` box to confirm that it's defined (it is).  So what am I missing here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The `action` attribute is missing a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a weird thing with how forms work with Javascript - each field is accessible by using `formElement.fieldName`. Unfortunately, that means that if you name a field input `submit`, all of a sudden the built-in `formElement.submit()` function is replaced by your input element. So in your code, `document.signup_form.submit()` is failing because it is calling the element, not the method, and you can't call an element as a function. See this [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript) for details.

The fix is easy - change:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email">
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Send Email">
```

---

Also, as others have noted, you will want to give your form a valid action. Also, in general it might be preferred to access things by id (`document.getElementById()`) instead of by things like `document.signup_form`.

Comment: Thank you!  Renaming the button did the trick...I'm glad it was a slightly more subtle point than some typo!

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` element is missing a value in it's `action` attribute. Quoting the specs:

> You also have to specify the URL of the service that will handle the
>   submitted data, using the action attribute

Link [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#configuring-a-form-to-communicate-with-a-server)

Comment: I actually had <?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?> within the action field originally but took it out in the process of debugging.  You're technically correct but, in the old school ways, it worked and may have been kept around still for compatibility reasons: 

9. If action is the empty string, let action be the document's address.

Note: This step is a willful violation of RFC 3986, which would require base URL processing here. This violation is motivated by a desire for compatibility with legacy content. [RFC3986]