# Cypress: "TypeError: form.submit is not a function"

Tags: javascript, cypress

I was making a spec file to test my forms in Cypress when suddenly this pops out:

**TypeError: form.submit is not a function**
: __cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:67597:14

This is the code:

```
cy.get(form).within(($form) => {    

    cy.root().submit();

});
```

You can clearly see the part that causes the error is the `cy.root().submit();` line.
but then when I check the element on the console, this comes out:

[root output on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WQRC.png)

So, it's a form!

I've got the code from here https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Forms

Screenshot of the run:

[Run test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoN74.png)

**What am I missing? Am i missing some dependency maybe?**

PD: I am using chrome 79

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the wait also before the form submit (the route could still in progress without that).

(You probably can delete then the second wait)

Edit:

```
cy.server();
cy.route(formRequest.method, formRequest.url).as('form-submit');
cy.wait('@form-submit').its('status').should('eq', 200);
cy.root().submit();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer.
I tried your solution but this time this error pops up:
`CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'form-submit'. No request ever occurred.`
since now he awaits forever the request and does not continue, therefore the request will never be sent.

Comment: you may try to remove the second wait, since you already awaited it now. Basically you can just move/replace the existing wait before the submit. I edited the answer.

Comment: It does exactly the same since the first wait does not continue untill it sees the request, and by then the request has not been triggered yet. Anyway I tried to remove everything from the within leaving only `cy.get(form).within(()=> {cy.root().submit();})` and the problem **TypeError: form.submit is not a function** keeps apearing. the cy.root() still yelds the form element.