# JavaScript: location.replace doesn't work in the function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, listener

I'm making a web app and I'm struggling with replacing the page.
In the function `myPage()`, when I put the `location.replace("file.html");` in the start, it works if I don't insert `inputs` on the web app, but when I put the `location.replace("file.html");` in the `if` statement then doesn't work at all, and is there where I need to put the `location.replace`.

Please help me.

js code:

```
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    submit.addEventListener("click",myPage);

    function myPage(){
        //location.replace("file.html"); // here this is working
        var name=document.formId.nameRadio.value;//name="abc"
        if (name=="abc"){
            location.replace("file.html");//but here not
        }
    }
```

html code:

```
<form  id="formId" name="formId" >
        <label>sth </label><br><br>
        <label for="name"> name  </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>sth</legend>
        <ul class="class-radio" >
            <li> <input  type="radio" name="nameRadio" id="abc" value="abc" required><label for="abc">abc</label></li>
            <li> <input  type="radio" name="nameRadio" id="cdf" value="cdf"><label for="cdf">cdf</label></li>

        </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="next" >
        </form>
```

Comment: Well the most likely reason is that `name` is not equal to "abc".

Comment: I can't understand your description of the problem.

Comment: @Pointy thank you for answer me,but its not this....because i have tested it by printing sth in the if statement...and it was printed...

Comment: submit buttons submit so you have two actions happening at once.... `console.log()` is your friend with debugging values.

Comment: @Barmar I'm really sorry but i'm not native speaker of english.thank you

Comment: @epascarello thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the usual form submission by adding `preventDefault()` to your onClick function.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.addEventListener("click", myPage);


function myPage(e) {
  //prevent form submission
  e.preventDefault();

  var name = document.getElementById('formId').nameRadio.value;
  if (name == "abc") {
    location.replace("file.html"); 
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="formId" name="formId">
  <label>sth </label><br><br>
  <label for="name"> name  </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>sth</legend>
    <ul class="class-radio">
      <li> <input type="radio" name="nameRadio" id="abc" value="abc" required><label for="abc">abc</label></li>
      <li> <input type="radio" name="nameRadio" id="cdf" value="cdf"><label for="cdf">cdf</label></li>

    </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="next">
</form>
```

Comment: You should explain what the problem was and how you solved it, not just post code.

Comment: Yep. I think I whacked it by accident.

Answer (score 1):

change your button type to button. your browser submits first.

```js
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    submit.addEventListener("click",myPage);

    function myPage(){
        //location.replace("file.html"); // here this is working
        var name=document.formId.nameRadio.value;//name="abc"
        alert(name);
        if (name=="abc"){
            location.replace("file.html");//but here not
        }
    }
```

```html
<form  id="formId" name="formId" >
        <label>sth </label><br><br>
        <label for="name"> name  </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>sth</legend>
        <ul class="class-radio" >
            <li> <input  type="radio" name="nameRadio" id="abc" value="abc" required><label for="abc">abc</label></li>
            <li> <input  type="radio" name="nameRadio" id="cdf" value="cdf"><label for="cdf">cdf</label></li>

        </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="next" >
        </form>
```

Comment: Was thinking the same

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want more control over the form submit.
You can change the input type from submit to button; Also rename that button to avoid [confusion with submit method of the form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834197/194717). 
You can also simplify the code, by using the click event directly on the input.
Here is something you can try:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form id="formId" name="formId">
         <label>sth</label><br><br>
         <label for="name">name</label>
         <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
         <fieldset>
            <legend>sth</legend>
            <ul class="class-radio">
               <li><input type="radio" name="nameRadio" id="abc" value="abc" required><label for="abc">abc</label></li>
               <li><input type="radio" name="nameRadio" id="cdf" value="cdf"><label for="cdf">cdf</label></li>
            </ul>
         </fieldset>
         <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="next" onclick="mySubmit()">
      </form>
      <script>
           function mySubmit()
           {
               var name = document.formId.nameRadio.value;
               if (name == "abc"){
                   location.replace("file.html");
               } else {
                   // Submit a form
                   document.formId.submit();
               }
           }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```