# Cannot click on submit button using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

Hi I am trying to login to https://rocket-league.com/ using Selenium. I have managed to login successfully using POST request method in BeautifulSoup but now I have to use Selenium because after logging into the website I have to click on a button, which I cannot do using BeautifulSoup.

There is a button in the form that says 'GO' which logins to website once the email and password are correct. I have tried the submit() method but got the following error :
**javascript error: arguments[0].submit is not a function
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)

homepage_URL = 'https://rocket-league.com'

driver.get(homepage_URL)
driver.find_element_by_id('acceptPrivacyPolicy').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('header-email').send_keys('email')
driver.find_element_by_id('header-password').send_keys('password') 
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/input[4]')
btn.submit()
```

Then I tried the **click()** method but I got a different error: **ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1077, 17)
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)**

I have successfully logged into the website using BS post method by posting required values to the php form.

```
data = {'email':'email','password':'password','csrf_token':token,'rememberme':'on','submit':'Go'}
url = 'https://rocket-league.com/functions/login.php'
result = s.post(url,data=data,cookies= cookie)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you were very close in the attempt with selenium. Try this some changes and it will start working -

Maximize the window  -  sometimes websites are not responsive and by default chrome opens in small window. When selenium locates **Go** button element it is not in the view and hence the error

Use proper locators or relative xpath. Absolute xpath makes the scripts flaky.

```
homepage_URL = 'https://rocket-league.com'

driver.get(homepage_URL)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_id('acceptPrivacyPolicy').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('header-email').send_keys('email')
driver.find_element_by_id('header-password').send_keys('password') 
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@value="Go"]')
btn.click()
```

**Output** -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

submit function works only with html form , as login form is a submit in the page it should work.

But when you try the submit action we get the following error:

[image]

This because the form field ahs one field with name submit , the button element name is given as "submit"

This is why only click() works .

But for other pages, you can use submit() on any form fields

["Submit is not a function" error in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript)

Comment: I checked that post before and tried the same approach on my code but I wasn't able to solve my problem. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: yes it is not working because name of the button is submit

Comment: there should not be any field with that name

Comment: Yes I am aware of that now thanks to your explanation :)