# SweetAlert isConfirm does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to show a [Sweet Alert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) confirm message to user after submitting the form like this:

```
<form id="myForm" data-flag="0" action="" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <input type="checkbox" id="btn-submit" name="wallet_checked" onchange="this.form.submit();">
</form>
```

As you can see I have used `onchange="this.form.submit();"` to submit the form without using submit button and it works fine.

Then I tried adding this as script for showing SweetAlert message to user:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal(
        {
        title: "Attention!",
        text: "Are you sure you want to make this",
        type: "warning",
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false
    },

    function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            console.log("YES");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

So the function shows Sweet Alert message on screen after clicking on the checkbox, but when I press on **Yes** button, it does not run `console.log("YES");`.

And this means that `if (isConfirm) {` at `function (isConfirm) {` is not working properly.

So how to solve this issue? What is wrong with `isConfirm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this to :

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = $(this).parents('form');
    swal(
        {
        title: "Attention!",
        text: "Are you sure you want to make this",
        type: "warning",
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false
    })
    .then((isConfirm) => {
        if (isConfirm) {
            console.log("YES");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank u, it shows `YES` at Console. But I tried submitting the form by saying `form.submit(); return true;` but does not call the action and just refreshes the page.

Comment: You are using  https://sweetalert.js.org/ not https://sweetalert2.github.io, both are different. if you want to make a ajax call then reffer to this link https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#ajax-requests