# jQuery stop or start form from posting

Tags: jquery

I have this form here:

```
<form method="post" name="homeForm" id="homeForm" action="thank-you-page.php">
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#homeForm").on("submit", function(e){

    var formData = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax({url: "email-check.php", dataType: "json", data: formData, type: "POST", cache: false, contentType: false, processData: false, success: function(result){
    
                    if(result.length > 0)
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('.modal').modal('show'); 
                        return false;
                    }
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
    
                }});
        
        

});
```

What I am trying to do is onSubmit do a check to an api via ajax call and if the result is greater than 0 prevent the default and show a modal, if the result length is equal to 0 carry onto the thank you page with the post data. The problem I am facing is that I am always redirected to the thank you page and preventDefault is not stopping the form in time. If I put preventDefault outside of the ajax call I see my modal but if the result is 0 I do not goto the thank you page.

UPDATE

I tried this:

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({url: "email-check.php", dataType: "json", data: formData, type: "POST", cache: false, contentType: false, processData: false, success: function(result){

                if(result.length > 0)
                {
                    $('.modal').modal('show'); 
                }
                {
                    e.target.submit();
                }

            }});
```

And I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: e.submit is not a function`

Comment: You need to put `e.preventDefault()` in the main function, not the callback. Then in the callback you call `e.target.submit()` to submit the form for real.

Comment: @Barmar I get this error: e.target.submit is not a function

Comment: Do you have `name="submit"` in the form? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-in-javascript

Comment: Yes I do have name="submit" in my input submit button

Comment: Give it a different name. See the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preventDefault in the submit handler
THEN do the Ajax
THEN decide to submit the actual form

```js
$("#homeForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  const form = this; // save the form
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "email-check.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.length > 0) $('.modal').modal('show');
      else form.submit(); // submit the form using the native form element
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].submit is not a function when I do it without the `[0]` it does nothing when the result is 0.

Comment: See update......